# Only continue within for loop if button was pressed

Tags: swift, for-loop, wait, for-in-loop

I have following setup:
Classes A and B. Class A generates an array of settings of form `[["SettingCategory"]]`. Class B controls the view and contains 2 buttons and a submit button.
I iterate through the array of settings using a for-in loop. The user can chose opt1/opt2 for each setting and then submit the choice. He will then be asked the second, third,.. setting.
I am having troubles waiting for the user to submit his choice. My for loop just goes through all elements of the array without allowing any interactions. I do not need code, I would really appreciate a basic idea of how to do this properly.

Here is some simplified code:

```
class A{
   var settingCategories = [["Sound", "loud", "soft"], ["Brightness", "dark", "bright"]]
   
   for setting in settingCategories{
      if setting[0] == "Sound"{
         classB.showTheCategory(opt1: setting[1], opt2: setting[2])

         // here I want to wait for the user to choose "loud" or "soft" and then submit it.
         // I only want to continue, when the user submitted his choice!
         // my loop just iterates through all elements of the array and does not detect 
         // button taps.
      }
   }
}

class B{ // ViewController
   showTheCategory(opt1: String, opt2: String){
      // this ONLY generates and shows the buttons: opt1, opt2 and SUBMIT
   }
   detectButtonPressed(){
      // here I detect what button was pressed
   }
}
```

Because of my architecture I am not able to detect the pressed buttons within the `showTheCategory` function. I tried using a while loop within class A but I ended up getting an infinite loop. And I would not like to use a Timer since I do not know how long it takes the user to make and input. I looked up Notifications, but my for loop does not wait for properties to change, it just iterates through them quickly.

Comment: do you want to present the options one at a time and once selected user sees the next, and so on until all questions are asked?

Comment: @Pancho, thanks for your input. Yes thats exactly what i would like to achieve. As of now it just skips through all first elements and just displays the last one. But I would like to have it just as you described.

Comment: in this case you need two lists. One with the questions and second to hold question->answer. You then present the screen and load your first question. When user selects an answer you store it in your answers list and move to next question. And so on until you collect all of your answers.

Comment: @Pancho The problem would be, that I can not wait/stop until the "user selects an answer" to store it. It just loops through the whole array of questions and just presents the last question in the array.

Comment: You're not going to implement a loop. My solution will only move to the next element when user selects an option. Initially you only load the first element
user click -> save selection and move to next (if any)
user clicks -> save selection and move to next (if any)
user clicks -> save selection and move to next (if any)
no more options -> finish

Hope it makes sense now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some pseudo code

```
// create an array to hold your answers
var answers: [Answer] = []()
// create an array to hold your questions
var questions: [Question] 
var currentQuestion: Question {
    didSet {
       // every time this property updates show the new question
       self.showQuestion(self.currentQuestion)
    }
}

init(questions: [Question]) {
   // store the questions
   self.questions = questions
   // pop your first questions from the list and assign it as the current question
   // this would also trigger its didSet method to display the question
   self.currentQuestion = self.questions.pop()
}

func showQuestion(_ question: Question) {
   // display question on screen
   questionLabel.text = question.text
   firstButton.title = question.firstOption
   secondButton.title = question.secondOption
}

func onButtonClick(sender: UIButton) {
   // user selected an answer, you can now store it and move to your next question. Here is how you can do it
   
   // create your answer and store it
   let answer = Answer(currentQuestion.text, answer: sender.title)
   self.answers.append(answer)
   // check if there is more questions in the list
   if self.questions.count > 0 {
      there is more questions so take one and show it the user
      self.currentQuestion = self.questions.pop()
   } else {
     // you have finished with all questions
     // you have successfully looped through all questions
     // and all user answers are now stored in your answers array
     // do with your answers whatever you need to. You're now done with asking questions :)
   }
}
```

This demonstrates the logic you could use to achieve what you're looking for. There is no need to implement `for` loops as you only need to wait for the user input. Once you receive the user input you store it and move to the next question and this is how you will eventually loop through all the questions. Hope it makes sense

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It helped me achieving exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You don't detect button presses "within the `showTheCategory` function." That's not how Swift works. All you need to do inside the loop is add the button (with `showTheCategory` I assume).

Then, inside `showTheCategory` you can assign a handler to each button.

```
/// enum for listing possible button types
enum ButtonType {
    case sound
    case loud
    case soft
    case brightness
    case dark
    case bright
}

class A {
   var settingCategories = [["Sound", "loud", "soft"], ["Brightness", "dark", "bright"]]
   
   for category in settingCategories {

       /// loop again
       for setting in category {

            /// check each individual setting
            if setting == "Sound" {
                classB.showTheCategory(buttonType: .sound, opt1: setting[1], opt2: setting[2])
            }
        }
    }
}

class B {
    func showTheCategory(buttonType: ButtonType, opt1: String, opt2: String) {
        // this ONLY generates and shows the buttons: opt1, opt2 and SUBMIT
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
        button.setTitle(opt1, for: .normal)
        
        switch buttonType {
        case .sound:
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(detectButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        case .loud:
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(detectLoudButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        case .soft:
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(detectSoftButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        case .brightness:
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(detectBrightnessButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        case .dark:
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(detectDarkButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        case .bright:
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(detectBrightButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }
    
    @objc detectSoundButtonPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
    }
    @objc detectLoudButtonPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
    }
    @objc detectSoftButtonPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
    }
    @objc detectBrightnessButtonPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
    }
    @objc detectDarkButtonPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
    }
    @objc detectBrightButtonPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
    }
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately gives me the same problem. It is possible to use the buttons but only for the last element of the array. So in the example it loops through all elements and only shows the buttons for ["Brightness", "dark", "bright"], but it skips ["Sound", "loud", "soft"].

Comment: Ah, I think your loop is wrong. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm by no means an expert, but I think I could have a solution so you could try this out:

So, assuming that both your showCategory and detectButtonPressed functions are working properly, an option could be using a DispatchGroup and some async code to make this work. Basically do something like this.

```
class A{
   var settingCategories = [["Sound", "loud", "soft"], ["Brightness", "dark", "bright"]]
   let dispatcher = DispatchGroup()
   let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "Doesn't really matter", qos: .background)
   dispatchQueue.async{
      for setting in self.settingCategories{
         if setting[0] == "Sound"{
            classB.showTheCategory(opt1: setting[1], opt2: setting[2], dispatcher: dispatcher)
            self.dispatcher.wait()
         }
      }
   }
}

class B{ // ViewController
   var dispatcherB = DispatchGroup()
   showTheCategory(opt1: String, opt2: String, dispatcher: DispatchGroup){
      // Here you should change the dispatcherB

      dispatcherB = dispatcher
      dispatcher.enter()
      DispatchQueue.main.async{
         // display buttons here
      }
   }
   detectButtonPressed(){
      // when the button is pressed do this
      dispatcherB.leave()
   }
}
```

If you're unfamiliar with dispatch groups and queues, groups basically are a way to wait for a portion of code to run before doing something else, and queues in this case are used to run parts of code that you want to run simultaneously. For example if you want to display a view and detect user interaction while running your for-loop which has to stop at every setting. If you would run the for-loop before changing your view and not at the same time, your screen would freeze and the user would not be able to do anything. That is why the combinations of dispatch groups and queues should do the trick.

Another thing I'm wondering about is why are you running this in two different classes. If you would be running everything on the same class, you could actually change the displayed buttons within detectButtonPressed() which would make things much easier. Either way I hope this helps you hahaha.

Comment: No need to be an expert for trying to help! Thanks for your time and detailed answer. I will look into it tonight after work and let you know if it helped. Thanks again, your answer is very much appreciated :)

Comment: No problem, glad I was able to help. I would also check out @Pancho's solution because it is the more standard way to do what you want to do, although I think that you could make it work with what you have. Let me know if you need any more help.